# Merging Multiple Text Files - StreamWriter Not Writing One File?

Tags: c#, streamreader, streamwriter

I simply want to merge all text files in a given directory, similar to the following command prompt command:

```
cd $directory
copy * result.txt
```

I've written the following code, which almost accomplishes what I want, but it's doing something strange.  When the `StreamWriter` writes the first file (or when `i = 0`), it doesn't actually write any content - the file size remains 0 bytes, despite the first file being ~300 KB.  However, the other file writes execute successfully.

If I compare the output from the command prompt to the output from the C# code in diff, you can see that a large block of text is missing.  Additionally, the command prompt result is 1,044 KB where the C# result is 700 KB.

```
string[] txtFiles = Directory.GetFiles(filepath);
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filepath + "result.txt"))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < txtFiles.Length; i++)
    {
       using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(txtFiles[i]))
       {
           writer.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());
       }
     }
}
```

Am I using the `StreamWriter` / `StreamReader` incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

Here, hope it helps you. Note: By copying from a stream to another you save some ram and greatly improve performance.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string filePath = @"C:\Users\FunkyName\Desktop";
        string[] txtFiles = Directory.GetFiles(filePath, "*.txt");

        using (Stream stream = File.Open(Path.Combine(filePath, "result.txt"), FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < txtFiles.Length; i++)
            {
                string fileName = txtFiles[i];
                try
                {
                    using (Stream fileStream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                    {
                        fileStream.CopyTo(stream);
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    // Handle file open exception
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `FileMode.OpenOrCreate` would add all files a second time to the output file, when the program runs again in the same directory. Rather use `FileMode.Create` to overwrite it completely or `FileMode.CreateNew` to get an exception when it already exists.

Comment: @Herdo The program deletes any existing folder matching the `filePath` variable prior to running, so this implementation should be OK.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Minimalistic implementation, reading the bytes and writing them instead of using a stream for reading - please note, that you should handle the IOException correctly to avoid misbehavior:

```
var newline = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Environment.NewLine);
var files = Directory.GetFiles(filepath);
try
{
    using (var writer = File.Open(Path.Combine(filepath, "result.txt"), FileMode.Create))
        foreach (var text in files.Select(File.ReadAllBytes))
        {
            writer.Write(text, 0, text.Length);
            writer.Write(newline, 0, newline.Length);
        }
}
catch (IOException)
{
    // File might be used by different process or you have insufficient permissions
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote your code , it works properly!  only change the line :

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filepath + "result.txt"))
```

to:

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filepath + "/result.txt"))
```

i guess you can't see the file because it is saved in another folder .